# facebook opengraph not updating and other questions

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm having a problem using Facebook's OpenGraph. I'm attempting to implement timeline features into my application. However, when try changing my meta tags to change the tile of my object, the changes are not reflected. When I pass my url into the debugger tool facebook offers, it displays that my OG object is still using the old data, as opposed to the new data. However, the weird thing is the raw properties show my changes. How do I get facebook to update the OG object?

Another problem I'm having is that when I make changes to my actions, facebook isn't properly updating it. When I reopen the action, it's still referencing my old object titles. For example, if a title of one of my movie objects was "sci fi," and I reference "sci fi" in the action "see," it will still be referencing "sci fi" even if I try to change it to something else. I would save and it, but when I reopened the action the old settings where still there.

I was also wondering about dynamic generation of objects. For example, if I had an app that allowed people to list movies they've watched, could I dynamically generate the OG object so that users can have the "see a $movie" show up in their timeline no matter what movie it was? The reason I'm wondering is because right now I'm unsure whether or not I need to keep the page with the meta tags up after I use it once.

Sorry for the word blocks and if my questions seem basic to you. I'm pretty much a newbie at this.

Comment: Uneducated idea: Try passing your url with an additional variable like "example.org?var=1", could be that facebook uses caching or sth. similar and only updates the new data every x hours. I hardly doubt that it's possible to set the og tags/objects only once and then delete them later.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm going to try this.

Comment: @ Dan Surfrider It works perfectly. I created a dynamic page and it properly updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting your URL into the Object Debugger should force Facebook to crawl it. Do you have your `og:url` pointing to the old URL?

I don't understand your second question. Is Facebook not crawling your page? It should recrawl every 7 days or you can force it with the scrape API.

For your third question, yes, you can do that. Just make a different URL for each movie with a different `og:url`. For good SEO you want to do `example.com/movie/1234/The-Matrix`.

Comment: Hi, my og:url is pointing to the same url that I'm trying to get facebook to crawl, and that has my meta tags on it. My second question is about the facebook settings where you define your objects and actions. It's not taking in the changes I make to my actions. For the third, I don't wish to permanently hold onto the web page. I was thinking more of using a GET with the info to a single web page, which generates the meta tags on the fly. Would that be properly read by facebook?

Comment: Hi, for my third question you are right, dynamic pages work perfectly fine. Finally got it to work. There was a problem with my og:url property pointing to a wrong folder, which was the source of my frustrations.

Comment: @saccharine could you please post a code snippet? I'm still having those frustrations.

Comment: @Lego Well, I don't know if my code snippet would help out much since it was really a stupid mistake on my part. Maybe you can post a new question and I'll take a look at it and see if I can spot any mistakes?

Comment: @saccharine Thanks! : ]
In short I did this: `<?php $params = $_GET; ?> <meta property="og:type" content="<?php echo $params['type'] ?>"/>`
It does localy, what it should but the Facebook Debugger seems to swallow my query string ( `?type=somethinghere` )

Comment: @Lego Without knowing more about your code, I can't help you much. You should probably post this as a new question with more information about what the facebook debugger is showing, including any warnings or error messages. However, from what I can tell you're passing in get parameters and using them in your meta tags. There can be a lot of things that go wrong here. Fb oftentimes chews up anything after an & sign in its apis. Are you using multiple get params? Is your url well formed? Have you checked the exact url you are putting into the debugger? What does it say when you view source?

Comment: @saccharine Sorry, I just had no time for posting my question in a proper way until now. [Here it goes](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/q/8431694/601466). And thanks again : ]

Answer (score 1):

> http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
>   Try this and put the link of the page you want facebook to clear its cache for.

Comment: The question states that the author is already using the debug tool.