# og:image doesn't show

Tags: image, facebook-opengraph

I've been testing the open graph tags for facebook and I can't get my logo to show when I share my website link on facebook.

If I use the lint debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) I get:

```
**Open Graph Object Properties**
og:url  http://www.movimenting.me/
og:type website
og:title    http://www.movimenting.me/
og:updated_time 1318267537

**Raw Open Graph Document Information**
Canonical URL   http://www.movimenting.me/
Meta Tag    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="210576275672723" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.movimenting.me/images/logo2.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:title" content="Movimenting.me" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.movimenting.me" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Movimenting.me" />
```

You can see that it gets the og:image on the raw part, but doesnt on the object properties..

Why is this? I always specify the same URL and opengraph.in gets the right tags..

thanks in advance.

---

everything comes out clean now on lint:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.movimenting.me%2F

image, locale, you name it. no errors or warnings or others.

BUT STILL, when you share the link (www.movimenting.me) on facebook, no image apears.

What can I do now, or what should I look for now?

Oh, btw now i recall: if I remove the og:image tag, it will indeed find 30 images to share, but not the logo. It's so strange, since the logo is the first one..

what now?

thanks in advance

Comment: It seems facebook is caching crawled pages:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12982729/2086561

Answer (score 1):

Is there any errors in the debugger? Maybe the app_id doesn't match that domain?

Comment: Changed that. Now it does. No change =/ It now recognizes the image on lint but doesn't show on FB when sharing. just so strange! =/

Comment: i had a [simmilar issue](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7268239/share-application-url-issue) with facebook's share feature... it seems you are not the only one! and that the problem in on facebook's side...

Answer (score 0):

Late reply but I've been having the same problem even though Facebook debug would report no issues and finally fixed it.

Nothing would show up when I had a 50x50px image which Facebook didn't complain about in the debugger.  I finally changed the image URL to use a 128x128px one.  It worked even though Facebook complained that the image should be at least 200x200px which I then used.

You can see the fix working here. https://www.thesuiteq.com