# og:image doesn't appear on Facebook when link is shared

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags, meta

My `og:image` doesn't show up on Facebook when I share a link to my webpage, I've researched a variety of answers to similar problems here on Stack Overflow, but haven't found a solution yet. Here's what I've read about it so far:

[1x1 px og image facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216136/1x1-px-og-image-facebook/25216164#25216164)

[og:image doesn't show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716557/ogimage-doesnt-show)

[Facebook don't display correct thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345652/facebook-dont-display-correct-thumbnail)

Also looked at a few other potential answers as I was composiung this question. Here's what the Facebook debugger returns as what it is seeing regarding my HTML:

```
</script><meta property="fb:app_id" content="1754277741470441">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://breadandcircuses.comicgenesis.com/images/spock-1.png">
<meta property="og:description" content="Bread and Circus comics for all your social and political commentary needs.">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://breadandcircuses.comicgenesis.com/">
<meta property="og:title" content="Bread and Circuses">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
```

All the other meta og tags appear to be working properly, my image size is not optimized for display on Facebook but it is 200x354, and the debugger returns that it is a 1x1 image.

Comment: `http://breadandcircuses.comicgenesis.com/images/spock-1.png` returns a 1x1 pixel image for me in my browser already.

Comment: That's the problem, the hosted image definitely isn't 1x1. I added it to th bottome of the page as a regular image (not meta) to see if that made a difference, still shows up blank when I share the link and in the scrape data, but if you click on the blank scrape data image, it takes you to the appropriately sized, visible image now.

Comment: I am not talking about the FB scraper here – even if I call that image URL in my browser directly, I only get a 1x1 pixel image. So you need to find out what makes your server answer that request that way.

Answer (score 1):

I found this debug tool in a similar question on facebook help.

https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200708365214182

The suggestion was to use the facebook debug link tool

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

It provides a list of warnings. I just changed a site from one hosting company to another and there may also be a propagation period for all search providers to align! :s

Comment: My og:image wasn't at least 200x200